# How can I submit the same GUID multiple times in a Visual Studio Code REST Client request

Tags: rest, visual-studio-code

When I need to use the same GUID in several instances - e.g. HTTP Header and Body - how can I achieve this?

Doing it like this generates multiple GUIDs:

```
...
###
POST https://host.acme.com/someapi
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Correlation-Id: {{$guid}}

{
  "CorrelationId": "{{$guid}}",
  "Record": [
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by defining and using a variable

```
...
###
@corrid = {{$guid}}
POST https://host.acme.com/someapi
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Correlation-Id: {{corrid}}

{
  "CorrelationId": "{{corrid}}",
  "Record": [
...
```

Comment: How can this be done across different requests?